# NFS+Kerberos+AD

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos, nfs

*Исходные данные:*

`srv1` - Ubuntu 14.04 NFS server

`clent1` - Ubuntu 14.04 NFS client

Оба узла [введены в AD](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD_windows), доменная авторизация работает, uid везде одинаковые.

*Что хотелось бы получить:* 
доменный пользователь `Vasya` после логина на `client1` мог бы смонтировать только свою папку `srv1:/export/Vasya`. На сколько я понимаю для этого используется `NFS+Kerberos`. Нормального руководства найти не удалось (или они не совместимы с руководством по вводу в AD).

Если кто решал подобную задачу прошу помочь:-)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте сетевую шару в /etc/fstab - тогда Вася сможет ее смонтировать. Конечно, смонтировать ее сможет и Петя - но у Пети все равно не будет доступа к файлам.

Надо понимать, что NFS - вещь довольно низкоуровневая, и не следит за тем, какой пользователь что монтирует, в принципе. На уровне NFS авторизация если и происходит - то авторизуется компьютер clent1 на сервере srv1, авторизация пользователей - это уже задача других слоев ОС.

Отсюда следствие - если client1 - не ваш компьютер (права рута не нем есть у кого-то кроме вас), то к вашей NFS-шаре ему доступ давать нельзя, ведь подменить uid при наличии прав рута - раз плюнуть.

Если требуется авторизация именно уровня пользователя, а не компьютера - используйте протокол SMB, а не NFS. Не смотря не все его недостатки, он лучше приспособлен для таких задач.

Comment: 1.) SMB не возможности использовать, только NFS

2.) `Vasya` пройдя аутентификация получает `билет kerberos`, на основании этого `srv1` видит что за `clent1` сидит именно `vasya` и разрешает ему монтирование шары.

Comment: Как использовать NFS - я уже написал.

Comment: Вы описали самый простой вариант, в данном контексте он не подходит
Если использовать `билет kerberos` то даже если `Vasya` получает root на `clent1` и поменяет `uid` чужую шару смонтировать он её не сможет

Comment: @PavelMayorov, nfs-сервер, насколько я понимаю, умеет отдавать export-ы только по kerberos-билетам: https://wiki.debian.org/NFS/Kerberos

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, al7, nfs-сервер просто *не умеет* проверять билет пользователя! Он проверяет лишь билет клиентского хоста. Если нужна проверка билетов пользователя - используйте другие технологии.

Comment: PavelMayorov, спасибо за уточнение. @al7, может быть, имеет смысл рассмотреть что-нибудь вроде, например, sshfs.